# How to pass error from network class to ViewController using call back

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

There is a networking class where, I have written multiple functions for multiple API class. I am using Decodable for decoding the response. I want to pass the error to my ViewController, so that I can take proper decision as per the error. `UserDetail` is my model which conforms to Codable. My problem is the error completion block. Compiler giving error `Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UserDetail'` if I am doing something like `completion(nil, error)`

```
func getUserDetails(_ id:String, queryParamDict: [String: Any], completion:@escaping (UserDetail, Error?)-> Void)
{
    let urlString = requestPathDiscovery.userDetailsURL(id, queryParamDict: queryParamDict)
    sessionManager.adapter = NetworkRequestAdapter()
    sessionManager.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON    { response in
        guard response.result.isSuccess else {
            // handle failure
            return
        }
        if let data = response.data {
            // init the decoder here
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do{
                let userResponse = try decoder.decode(UserDetail.self, from: data)
                completion(userResponse, nil)
            }
            catch let error {
                 /** Here I am getting the problem **/
                //completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UserDetail**

```
class UserDetail: Codable
{
 var result: User
}
class User: Codable{
 var d: String?
 var name: String?
 var phoneNumber:String?
 var gender:String?
 var dateOfBirth:UInt64?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function's completionHandler has to take an optional `UserDetail` since there won't be any user details in the error case:

`func getUserDetails(_ id:String, queryParamDict: [String: Any], completion:@escaping (UserDetail?, Error?)-> Void) { ...`

Comment: If I'll make the UserDetail optional, I'll get some unnecessary check wherever I have to use UserDetail. Isn't there is some other way to pass error.

Comment: You could use two completion handlers. One for the success case that includes a `UserDetail` object and one for the error case with an `Error` object.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
func getUserDetails(_ id:String, queryParamDict: [String: Any], completion:@escaping (UserDetail?, Error?)-> Void)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate design pattern. Define 2 method signature on your delegate protocol 'onSuccess (result: yourSuccessResult)' 'onError (error: yourError)'. Now call delegate properties 'onSuccess' method if you get data properly and 'onError' if error occurs.